# Why wont my SET value WHERE SQL Statement not work

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Currently cant get this to work, despite it being almost for verbatim the same as else where in my code.

```
  Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE " & "`" & "SIQPERSIST" & "`" & " SET [Date_Added] = @Date_Added WHERE [BatchName] = @BatchName", con)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchName", BatchName2)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Added", Date.Now.ToShortDateString)

                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()


            End Using
        End Using
```

I'm working in Vb.net

and i need to update all rows that have the name BatchName2 (this comes from a textbox)
with the current date.
The table they are on is SIQPERSIST.

The error i get is that its missing a parameter.

But i have don't know what parameter it needs despite almost similar code working else where, except the working code uses a WHERE KEY= 'keynumber' statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this uses backticks for the concatenated variable. Remember, ` and ' are not the same thing, and only one of those would work here.

It should look like something more like this:

```vb
Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE SIQPERSIST SET [Date_Added] = Date() WHERE [BatchName] =  @BatchName", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchName", BatchName2)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Note, there's no need to call `con.Close()` when you have a `Using` block to take care of that for you.

Additionally, not only did I convert `BatchName2` to a real query parameter (Shame on you for adding concatenation to a query that already demonstrates how to use parameters!), but I was also able to convert the existing parameter to use get the date in the DB itself.

Comment: I'm using an Access Database.

Comment: iv updated the question to code that does work, but it still leaves one of the rows dates not updated to the new date. it still has the previous date.

Comment: @AndyAndromeda Fixed the answer to work for Access. If it's missing a row, it's probably because the Date_Added column doesn't match current date. Remember: the comparison always checks the entire column, and never just the date portion.